# AT Commands for SMS delivery report

Tags: c#, at-command

I am working on project where i have to send SMS to presons. if the persons doesn't receives the SMS, I have to send him again. So, for i need successful SMS   delivery report. how to get and read SMS delivery status or report.? i am using SIMCOM 800 device and project language is c#.net (console appplication).

Snippet Code Here...

Program.cs

```
public void SendSMS(string sim, string message)
        {
            //.............................................. Send SMS ....................................................
            try
            {

                if (objclsSMS.sendMsg(this.port, sim, message))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Message has sent successfully");
                    Console.WriteLine("Message has sent successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Failed to send message");
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to send message");
                }
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

clcSMS.cs

```
    #region Send SMS

            static AutoResetEvent readNow = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            public bool sendMsg(SerialPort port, string PhoneNo, string Message)
             {
                bool isSend = false;

                try
                {

                    string recievedData = ExecCommand(port, conncetioncmd, 300, "No phone connected");
                    recievedData = ExecCommand(port, msgformatcmd, 300, "Failed to set message format.");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSMP=49,167,0,242", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CNMI=1.0.0.1.0", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");
                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CNMI=1,1,0,0,0", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CNMI=1,0,0,1,0", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CNMI=2", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSMP=49,167,0,0", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");
                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CNMI=2,2,0,1,0", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    //recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CSAS", 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo"); 

                    String command = msgcmd + PhoneNo + "\"";
                    recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 300, "Failed to accept phoneNo");

                    command = Message + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
                    recievedData = ExecCommand(port,command, 3000, "Failed to send message"); //3 seconds
                    if (recievedData.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))
                    {
                        isSend = true;
                    }
                    else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
                    {
                        isSend = false;
                    }
                    return isSend;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex; 
                }

            }     

            static void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (e.EventType == SerialData.Chars)
                        readNow.Set();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

            #endregion

  public string ExecCommand(SerialPort port,string command, int responseTimeout, string errorMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                port.DiscardOutBuffer();
                port.DiscardInBuffer();
                receiveNow.Reset();
                port.Write(command + "\r");

                string input = ReadResponse(port, responseTimeout);
                if ((input.Length == 0) || ((!input.EndsWith("\r\n> ")) && (!input.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))))
                    throw new ApplicationException("No success message was received.");
                return input;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohit i'll appreciate your question, am knowledge about android. 
In our case we are getting receiver for getting any system purpose messages.
so if you have any receiver for getting response from your device than you can get the report for sending message.. **But reading status is maybe not possible in this case you can get only delivered status** if functionality available in your C#(Console app).

Comment: Check bellow link if you intrest https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-confirm-delivery-in-csharp#how-it-works

Comment: https://mobiforge.com/design-development/handling-sms-delivery-receipts